# How to connect an AnsiString to a path [C++]

Tags: c++

I have this

```
strcpy (&rZipArchive[strlen(rZipArchive)],"\\"+"char(FileNameLog)", ".zip");
```

I'm trying to make a path out of it, ZipArchive is a path to a folder but i need to attach to that path "\FileNameLog.zip", FileNameLog contains the date of today 'dd_MM_yy'. The final result i'm searching for is rZipArchive\FileNameLog.zip --> C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4(all of it is contained into rZipArchive).

Comment: By repeating `strcat()`?

Comment: What is the type of `FileNameLog`?

Comment: char FileNameLog[MAX_DATE];

Comment: If this really is C++, why not just concatenate `std::string`s ?

Comment: `snprintf()` might be useful with conbination of your `strlen()` technique.

Comment: can you please give me some examples? i've  tryied the concat of the strings yet...maybe it was something werong... it's like 1 hour i'm on it

Comment: `std::string`  can be concatenated with other strings (even C-strings) through it's overloaded `+` operator.

Comment: the fact is the if i try to narmally concat every type, it unlock some issues on conversion types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format data and store the result as a string via `sprintf()`.

```
sprintf (&rZipArchive[strlen(rZipArchive)], "\\%s.zip", FileNameLog);
```

If you know the buffer size(`rZipArchiveSize` for example), using `snprintf()`, which accepts output size limit, is safer.

```
size_t len = strlen(rZipArchive);
if (len < rZipArchiveSize) {
    snprintf(&rZipArchive[len], rZipArchiveSize - len, "\\%s.zip", FileNameLog);
}
```